# VS Code gets confused if I put an SMGL comment (<!--hello-->) inside a style element in an HTML document?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

When using VS Code to write html, if I add embedded CSS in the style element, the syntax highlighting changes the document to be styled as if the entire document was CSS.

I have tried;

- Disabling all extensions and reloading VS Code.
- Removing all extensions entirely and reloading VS Code.
- Adding an association for html files for .html.

[image: Syntax highlighting without embedded CSS]

[image: Syntax highlighting with embedded CSS]

Comment: You have a HTML comment inside the stylesheet but CSS uses `/* */` style comments. Does changing or removing) the comment make a difference?

Comment: From MDN _"However, when using the `<style>` element, you may use `<!-- -->` to hide CSS from older browsers, although this is not recommended."_ It may be that the VS Code syntax highlighter doesn't support this.

Comment: Changing the comment to the css one inside the style element works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by the HTML comment in the style element. That's legal for older browsers, but see the following quote from [the CSS 2.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#comments):

> CSS also allows the SGML comment delimiters ("`<!--`" and "`-->`") in certain places defined by the grammar, but they do not delimit CSS comments. They are permitted so that style rules appearing in an HTML source document (in the STYLE element) may be hidden from pre-HTML 3.2 user agents. See the HTML 4 specification ([[HTML4]](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/refs.html#ref-HTML4)) for more information.

And [in the CSS 3 spec, `<!--` and `-->` basically just do nothing](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#consume-list-of-rules). The text between them will be treated as if they were written without the wrapping `<!--` and `-->`.

But I have no idea if VS Code's builtin language support for style elements in HTML is following the CSS spec with respect to that, or which spec version it's following.